# How to run a process after send response to client in jsp and servlet?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have a dynamic web project (JSP and Servlet):

1. Client uploads a file to server
2. Save client's file
3. Show "Your result will have in about 1h, we will send result to your email."
4. Process client's file
5. Send result to client's email.

How can I do (4)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Servlet 3.0, you can use its asynchronous feature. e.g.:

```java
@WebServlet(urlPatterns={"/processFile"}, asyncSupported=true)
@MultipartConfig
public class CorreoServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        // (2) Save client's file
        final Part filePart = request.getPart("file"); // <input name="file" ...

        ...

        AsyncContext asyncContext = req.startAsync();
        asyncContext.start(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // (4) Process client's file
                // (5) Send result to client's email.
            }
        });

        // (3) Show "Your result will ...

    }

}
```

Maybe you want to see:

- [Java File Upload Example with Servlet 3.0 API](http://www.codejava.net/java-ee/servlet/java-file-upload-example-with-servlet-30-api)
- [The Java EE 7 Tutorial : Asynchronous Processing](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/doc/servlets012.htm)
- [Java - Sending Email using JavaMail API](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_sending_email.htm)

Comment: I'm having an error: "A filter or servlet of the current chain does not support asynchronous operations". How can I fix it?

Comment: @storky Make sure you match the url pattern for the servlet and/or for the filter if any. `urlPatterns = "/*"` might help.

Comment: @storky If you have a filter, see this example: [Asynchronous Filter post processing](http://www.coderanch.com/t/553361/Servlets/java/Asynchronous-Filter-post-processing). =)

Answer (score 0):

You can use asynchronous process. You can use scheduler like [Quartz](http://quartz-scheduler.org/) to perform the task in background.

Comment: If you want to do in complete Java way here is one example http://www.devsumo.com/technotes/2013/10/java-web-apps-running-regular-background-tasks/ . However, I prefer Quartz Simple triggers over for this task.

Comment: Thank you very much! That is exactly what i want to find!